# SkImageDecoder factory returned null upon loading an image from resources

Tags: android

I'm trying to load an image into my image view using the following line of code:

```
iv_flagged.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_flagged);
```

However when I run this line of code, I get the a debug log cat message '07-16 16:12:03.610: D/skia(21114): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null'

The not_flagged image is definitely in the drawable folder.

I've loaded images into image views loads of times before, here, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, the file I thought was a .png was actually a .psd file, but with a .png file extention. Hence the image decoder thought it was invalid. Idiot!